# Combine NextAuth Credentials and Providers

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I want to connect my Nextjs project to Firebase for user auth. I have set up two providers, and I also want to include a traditional username and password sign in. I understand how adapters fit into the picture to hold the function necessary to persist the user data in the database.

My idea was to create all necessary user auth functions on the server, but I know there is an adapter available for Firebase that already has many of these functions.

- Are there any examples of integrating both credentials and providers
  with Firebase?
- Can I use these functions in the callbacks on
  credential login, and can I use these functions elsewhere in-app?